# If $A$ is skew-symmetric, then $x^T A^2 x \le 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms, skew-symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ be a skew-symmetric matrix. Show that for any vector $x$

$$x^T A^2 x \le 0$$

Since $A$ is skew-symmetric then $A^2$ is symmetric.  Then, I'm blocked. I tried to consider $a=x^T A^2 x$, but without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: If $A$ is skew-symmetric, then $x^TA = -x^TA^T$. Therefore 
$$x^TA^2x = -x^TA^TAx = -(x^TA^T)(Ax) = \ldots\ ?$$

Comment: Is $B^T B \ge 0$ for any $B$ : $-\left( x^T A^T \right) \left(A x \right) = - \left(A x \right)^T \left(A x \right) $

Comment: $= -\|Ax\|^2 \leq 0.$ Right.